# Lowercase a python string, referencing a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, `values`. In the following:

```
<cleared_for_sale>%(cleared_for_sale)s</cleared_for_sale>""" % values
```

the `cleared_for_sale` variable is either `True` or `False`. However, I need it to show as `true` or `false`. How would I lowercase this? I do not want to change the type of string formatting I am using (I cannot use `"string" % str(var).lower()`

Comment: why cant you use `str(var).lower()` ?

Comment: Why can't you use `str(var).lower()`?

Comment: @Blender +1 for &apos; :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how bout

`("""<cleared_for_sale>%(cleared_for_sale)s</cleared_for_sale>"""%values).lower()`

or maybe

`str(values).replace("T","t").replace("F","f")` ?

since you didnt explain why you cant use str(values).lower() ... both of these solutions answer your question as you currently have it phrased

Answer (score 0):

Change the value in the dictionary from a bool to a string before doing the formatting:

```
values['cleared_for_sale'] = str(values['cleared_for_sale']).lower()
```

And an alternative since you have some aversion to `str(var).lower()`:

```
values['cleared_for_sale'] = 'true' if values['cleared_for_sale']) else 'false'
```

Now when use use `% values` on the format string `%(cleared_for_sale)s` will be replaced by `true` or `false` instead of `True` or `False`, without any other behavior being modified.